# adding maven dependency causing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, reflection, json-simple, maven-dependency, janino

I have an application which is working fine until I have introduced the following maven dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compiler-jdk</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

After introducing the following dependencies, the jar is getting built properly, no compiler exceptions but when running the application, it is failing with the following exceptions:

Exception 1:

```
Exception in thread "2/streamJsonParser:StreamingJsonParser" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation
at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:165)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.error(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:540)
at com.datatorrent.stram.engine.StreamingContainer$2.run(StreamingContainer.java:1431)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 5 more
```

Exception 2:

```
Exception in thread "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.PeerCache@3826c025" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/LinkedListMultimap$3
at com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap.values(LinkedListMultimap.java:846)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.PeerCache.clear(PeerCache.java:271)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.PeerCache$1.run(PeerCache.java:128)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap$3
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
```

Exception 3:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/helpers/NullEnumeration
at org.apache.log4j.Category.getAllAppenders(Category.java:413)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.closeNestedAppenders(Category.java:226)
at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.shutdown(Hierarchy.java:467)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.shutdown(LogManager.java:267)
at com.datatorrent.stram.engine.StreamingContainer.main(StreamingContainer.java:332)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.helpers.NullEnumeration
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 5 morexception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ShutdownHookManager$2
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownHooksInOrder(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$2
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 2 more
```

Please let me know what needs to be done. I have tried adding some  as well but didn't work. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include following dependencies in your POM

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

These are missing and because of that you're getting exception.

Following is the screenshot of the POM Editor dependencies tab in STS. Latest eclipse should also have it.

[image]

You can also use following command to check dependencies.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: I tried adding these dependencies before and now as well, but it is the same issue. I am guessing the issue is because of duplicate dependencies rather than missing dependencies.

Comment: Can you help me understand if the above dependencies added by me adds any duplicate dependencies related to log4j or guava?

Comment: Jars are packed with the `artifactId-version` name, so any dependencies which you include with the same artifactId and version would be inlcuded only once. However you should check if you already have a different version of log4j, if you do then change the `log4j-extra` version to the version of your own log4j.

Comment: Moreover if you're using Eclipse/STS, then you should be able to verify transitive dependencies loaded in the `dependencies` tab of POM editor.

Comment: Yes, I am using eclipse. How can I verify transitive dependencies?

Comment: Then there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

```
mvn clean install -U
```

The `-U` ask maven to force update of dependencies.

Comment: I think if it is because of duplicate classes getting loaded not sure though on what to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer above as the user has explained me a way to identify the duplicate dependencies getting added.

It is actually an issue with duplicate hadoop dependencies from the POM and the run time environment.